# Passing java script function result to Angular ng-table

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have Angular ng-table where I load Json data to $data variable and display in the table.

```
function ngTable(){
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).
controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, ngTableParams) {
    var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
});
}
```

Additionally I have Java Script function returning some other Json data - function is called on button click.

```
function ReturnJson() {
 var json = []; 
 $('body').on('click','button#test', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("value").val();
   json = id;
  });
 return json;
}
```

How do I replace var data content with ReturnJson() every time on button click action ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple assignment will work, but remember to reload the grid:

```
$scope.loadData = function () {
  $scope.data = $scope.ReturnJson();
  $scope.tableParams.reload();
}

$scope.ReturnJson = function () {
  var json = [{name: "bb", age: 200},{name: "aaa", age: 100}];
  return json;
}
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jw41uCmHGAfjkuoLIQor?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure how to take advantage of your solution, because my java script function is called on Jquery onclick event and there is some ajax request inside ... But definitely +1 for the constructive response.

Comment: I am suggesting that you use angular's ng-click to call the function.  Angular has $http for ajax.  It really is easier not to mix angular and jquery.