# Change some part in URL as per Id using C#

Tags: c#, url, url-rewriting

I am using URL Rewriting for making URL better using C#. I am retrieving data base on Id and display title also in URL.
For i.e. Lets take URL of stackoverflow only.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422364/flattened-out-a-mixed-type-of-list
```

It mostly fetch data using Id which is `24422364`. Now, if I change ID manually in URL and then enter to fetch data, It automatically change title (in this url title means - flattened-out-a-mixed-type-of-list).
If I change id to '24422315' for example then It will redirect to URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422315/passing-java-script-function-result-to-angular-ng-table` to itself means It has change title also.
In my case, If user change Id then it fetchs new data for sure but It is not changing Title. So, how to do this ?
Please help me for this.
My page URL is : `www.example.com/Projects/5/this-is-something.html`, Page is `Project.aspx, 5 & this-is-something` is `QueryString`.

Comment: Once you change URL in a `string` then you have to call `Response.Redirect(URL);`

Comment: @HassanNisar, I had this one in mind. So, this one is the only solution ???

Comment: I am not sure about other solutions. But this one seems appropriate.

Comment: @HassanNisar, thank you. Lets see if I get any other suggestions.